# shouldEndSession, after the skill completes a task, the session remains open

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have a problem with the skill of my Alexa, I passed the certification for all but I have a return from them with these remarks:

---

After the skill completes a task, the session remains open with no prompt to the user. The skill must close the session after fulfilling requests if it does not prompt the user for any input.

Steps To Reproduce:

User: "Alexa, demande à astro wiki ou trouver du composite"
Skill: " le composite est une ressource commune à toutes les planètes. On en trouve un peu partout, il suffit de regarder autour de soi "
(The session remains open.)

Please note that the session should close immediately after the completion of the task. Only if the user is prompted for another interaction can the session remain open, to allow the user to answer and, if no answer is given, the session should then close.

Please refer to test case 4.1 from [the Submission Checklist](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/voice-interface-and-user-experience-testing-for-a-custom-skill.html#cert-session-management).

---

here is my code https://github.com/djangocassidy/skill_astrowiki/blob/master/lambda_index.js

Thank you

Comment: Remove `.listen(repromptSpeech)` and the session would end.

Comment: yes actually i did the test but when i delete the .listen Alexa no longer answers any question, the skill closes

Comment: the code is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

Facts skills are usually done that way: they answer a single question and they close the session. That's what the people in the certification expect. The problem here is that you keep your session open (listen()) and you ask nothing, no guidance. That's unacceptable from a certification stand point. What you have to do if you want users to keep asking questions is add text after the data you output that guides the user to keep interacting. Examples: "what else can i do for you?", "you can ask me xxx to continue", etc